# Gitosis on Ubuntu can only find repositories in the git->repositories symlink

Tags: path, repository, gitosis

I have `gitosis` on my Ubuntu box and suddenly, it can't find any repositories on the old path.

Yesterday this worked:

```
git clone git@mymachine.com:myproject.git
```

Today, I get the reply:

```
fatal: 'myproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

I have made no changes to my machine, and after some testing I found out that I could access the repository through the git symlink in `~gitosis` user directory, so this still works:

```
git clone git@mymachine.com:git/myproject.git
```

(the git symlinks points to "repositories" in the same dir)

I would very much like to avoid having to change the remote path in the config files of all my cloned projects. Can you help me how to configure git so I can access my repositories from the root path again?

Update: I found out that also I can't add new repositories any more. After adding a repo to `gitosis.conf`, setting the remote origin to include the `git/` dir and pushing it with

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

I get

fatal: 'mynewproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository

So now I can only update existing repositories, and only if I change the remote path to include the `git` dir.

Best,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that helped me was:

- backup repositories with tar czf repos.tgz
- backup gitosis.conf
- reinstall gitosis with aptitude remove gitosis && aptitude install gitosis
- move repositories back after gitosis-init with the old key
- checkout gitosis-admin and move the old gitosis.conf into the dir, and push it back

Now everything is running

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433198/gitosis-git-error-fatal-home-git-repositories-idea-generator-git-does-not/3500061#3500061), using the full path means bypassing gitosis completely. So your workaround isn't actually one, and that explains why `push` fails.

- Try [settings `loglevel` to `DEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634100/why-i-cant-add-new-repositories-using-gitosis/1638380#1638380) to check if you see anything on the gitosis side.
- Try [resetting the `authorized_keys` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907004/gitosis-configure-problem/3434698#3434698) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like gitosis is not really working at all because the only way to update gitosis.conf is to use the git/ path when pushing, and loglevel=DEBUG does not give me any extra output.

Comment: @user681814: I would rather install gitolite, with the from-client method: much more robust. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041067/gitolite-git-clone-error/5041898#5041898